# Mosaico missing templates

Tags: drupal, mosaico, templates, missing

With this fresh install, no templates are installed; the civicrm_mosaico_template table has no rows, although www-t1/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates does contain these subdirectories.

tedc15/
tutorial/
versafix-1/

```
This is with a new composer install. 
Drupal version   : 9.5.11
Site URI         : http://t1.boo.org
DB driver        : mysql
DB hostname      : localhost
DB port          : 3306
DB username      : boo_ut1
DB name          : boo_dt1
Database         : Connected
Drupal bootstrap : Successful
Default theme    : aristotle
Admin theme      : aristotle
PHP binary       : /opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/usr/bin/php
PHP config       : /opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/etc/php.ini
PHP OS           : Linux
PHP version      : 8.1.24
Drush script     : /home/boo/www-t1/vendor/drush/drush/drush
Drush version    : 11.6.0
Drush temp       : /tmp
Drush configs    : /home/boo/.drush/drush.yml
                   /home/boo/www-t1/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
Install profile  : opigno_lms
Drupal root      : /home/boo/www-t1/web
Site path        : sites/default
Files, Public    : sites/default/files
Files, Private   : /home/boo/www-t1/web/../private
Files, Temp      : /tmp

CiviCRM 5.66.0 (All extensions are up-to-date)
AuthX: Version 5.66.0
CiviContribute: Version 5.66.0
CiviEvent: Version 5.66.0
CiviGrant: Version 5.66.0
CiviMail: Version 5.66.0
CiviMember: Version 5.66.0
CiviReport: Version 5.66.0
CKEditor4: Version 5.66.0
Custom search framework: Version 5.66.0
Event Cart: Version 5.66.0
Financial ACLs: Version 5.66.0
FlexMailer: Version 5.66.0
Form Core: Version 5.66.0
Mosaico: Version 3.2.1691060437
reCAPTCHA: Version 5.66.0
SearchKit: Version 5.66.0
Sequential credit notes: Version 5.66.0
Theme: Greenwich: Version 5.66.0
```

With url path https://t1.boo.org/civicrm/mosaico-template-list, there are no templates displayed. Adding a template (which will autofill with Newletter if you type an 'n') the UI shows an error. "Sorry and error occurred and your information was not saved."

More dramatically this url path https://t1.boo.org/civicrm/admin/setting/mosaico?reset=1 produces 2800 line stack trace (including just a bit here:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "template" in include() (line 5 of /home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0B/0B9/0B956D8A%%Field.tpl.php).
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0B/0B9/0B956D8A%%Field.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 15)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%F9/F94/F94D3738%%basicFormFields.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 8)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%A5/A51/A512AFEC%%basicForm.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 19)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0C/0CB/0CBEC124%%default.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 61)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%F7/F77/F77C7890%%CMSPrint.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 6)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%2B/2BD/2BD99720%%drupal8.tpl.php') (Line: 1273)
Smarty->fetch('CRM/common/drupal8.tpl', NULL, NULL, ) (Line: 205)
CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch('CRM/common/drupal8.tpl') (Line: 117)
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->renderForm(Object) (Line: 83)
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object, 'display') (Line: 203)
HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object, 'display') (Line: 103)
HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('display') (Line: 355)
CRM_Core_Controller->run() (Line: 98)
CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run('CRM_Admin_Form_Generic', 'Mosaico Settings', Array) (Line: 295)
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) (Line: 69)
CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) (Line: 36)
CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array) (Line: 88)
Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke(Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main(Array, '')
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 169)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 718)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
Warning: Undefined array key "help" in include() (line 14 of /home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0B/0B9/0B956D8A%%Field.tpl.php).
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0B/0B9/0B956D8A%%Field.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 15)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%F9/F94/F94D3738%%basicFormFields.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 8)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%A5/A51/A512AFEC%%basicForm.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 19)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0C/0CB/0CBEC124%%default.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 61)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%F7/F77/F77C7890%%CMSPrint.tpl.php') (Line: 1914)
Smarty->_smarty_include(Array) (Line: 6)
include('/home/boo/www-t1/private/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%2B/2BD/2BD99720%%drupal8.tpl.php') (Line: 1273)
Smarty->fetch('CRM/common/drupal8.tpl', NULL, NULL, ) (Line: 205)
CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch('CRM/common/drupal8.tpl') (Line: 117)
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->renderForm(Object) (Line: 83)
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object, 'display') (Line: 203)
HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object, 'display') (Line: 103)
HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('display') (Line: 355)
CRM_Core_Controller->run() (Line: 98)
CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run('CRM_Admin_Form_Generic', 'Mosaico Settings', Array) (Line: 295)
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) (Line: 69)
CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) (Line: 36)
CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array) (Line: 88)
Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke(Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main(Array, '')
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 169)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 718)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: The null array seems to be the problem, an error not encountered until after php 7.4.

Comment: The warning from that stack trace appears to be from visiting the "Mosaico Settings" page rather than the Mosaico UI itself.

Comment: Yes, the Mosaico UI is just blank, just nothing there, no error; except if one attempts to create a new template, and typing 'n' does autofill with Newsletter, then there is a generic error pop-up, but nothing is logged.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem has to do with PHP versions, updating the PHP version, and backing out has always provoked and fixed the problem.  Finally one must just move forward with a supported PHP version, in which case changing the outbound mail setting from php 'mail()' to SMTP resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Mosaico 3.3, clear CiviCRM cache, and see if the error persists?  I suspect the [DAO rebuild](https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/pull/609) may have solved this issue.